# Can't set action in aui:form although I named the action in MVCPortlet

Tags: forms, liferay-6

I'm having a bit of a problem tracing where this error comes from, in my jsp I have a form set like this:

```
<jsp:useBean id="usuario" type="com.cide.cajaVirtual.EContinua.model.Estudiantes" scope="request">
</jsp:useBean>
<jsp:useBean id="compras" type="com.cide.cajaVirtual.EContinua.model.EstudiantesCompras" scope="request">
</jsp:useBean>

<% Calendar now = CalendarFactoryUtil.getCalendar(); %>
<portlet:actionURL name="registrarCompra" var="registrarCompraURL"> 
<aui:form name="fmCompra" action="<%=registrarCompraURL.toString() %>" method="post">
```

Then in my portlet class I have:

```
public class CajaVirtualPortlet extends MVCPortlet {
    /*
 * El portlet RegistroUsuariosComprasPortlet permite a los estudiantes llenar la    forma 
 * de registro y hacer una compra de la oferta de Educación Continua
 * 
 */

public void addCompra(ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response) throws   Exception {
    ThemeDisplay themeDisplay =
            (ThemeDisplay) request.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);


}

public void registrarCompra(ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response) throws   Exception {
}
```

But I keep getting the error on Eclipse that says "registrarCompraURL cannot be resolved"

I ask this because honestly I don't have an idea of what I'm doing wrong, as I said I lost trace of what I was doing while typing in Eclipse. Please someone help!

Comment: Have you deployed your portlet? Any error on console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect portlet action url tag is not closed thats why you are facing this issue.

Try `<portlet:actionURL name="registrarCompra" var="registrarCompraURL"/>`

Also make sure you have taglib declared for it like.
`<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet" %>`

Comment: thank you, it may sound strange but I had realized this upon returning to the post. So the code should have been  `<portlet:actionURL name="registrarCompra" var="registrarCompraURL"></portlet:actionURL> 
<aui:form name="fmCompra" action="<%=registrarCompraURL.toString() %>" method="post">` Many thanks anyhow. I also have declared the taglib as you pointed out. So that taglib is what declares any <portlet> tag, yes? Also I don't know how to close this question but if anyone can close it I'd be thankfull.